# C++ Protected Variables Not Inherited

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, member, protected

I have written some code to calculate the RSA cryptographic algorithm. The program uses classes and inheritance because I want to calculate a public and private key for multiple users. There is a parent class `rsa` and child classes `public_key` and `private_key`.

When compiling the code below, I get many errors. All of them are about the derived classes not having the available fields in their respective constructors (see error message below code). However, these variables are defined with the `protected` access modifier in the parent class, so they should be accessible to the child class.

One side note: I had the function `key` in both of the child classes, but I thought it would be better to put it once in the parent class, is this right?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class rsa
{
protected:
    int p, q, d, m, n, f, e, c, end, k;

public:
    rsa() : n(0), e(0), c(0), k(0), end(0), f(0)
    { }

    void set(int , int , int, int);

    int key()
    {
        n = p * q;
        f = (p - 1) * (q - 1);

        for (k; end < 1; k++)
        {
            if ((1 + k * f) % d == 0) 
            {
                end = 2;
                e = (1 + k * f) / d;
            }
        }

        c = int(pow(m, e)) % n;

        return c;
    }
};

void rsa::set(int p_, int q_, int d_, int m_)
{
    p = p_;
    q = q_;
    d = d_;
    m = m_;
}

class public_key : public rsa
{
public:
    public_key() : n(0), e(0), c(0), k(0), end(0), f(0)
    { }
};

class private_key : public rsa
{
public:
    private_key() : n(0), e(0), c(0), k(0), end(0), f(0)
    { }
};

int main()
{
    public_key usr1, usr2;
    private_key usr1r, usr2r;

    usr1.set(11, 5, 23, 9);
    usr2.set(13, 7, 97, 6);
    usr1r.set(17, 7, 51, 8);
    usr2r.set(11, 17, 51, 4);

    cout << "Public key of user 1: " << usr1.key() << endl;
    cout << "Public key o user 2: " << usr2.key() << endl;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

One of the errors:

```
error: class ‘private_key’ does not have any field named ‘e’
   private_key () : n(0), e(0), c(0), k(0), end(0), f(0) {} ;
```

All the other errors are the same but the field name changes.

Comment: Please post the exact error and location.

Comment: People would rather see the actual error message rather than being told your interpretation of the error message.

Comment: You cannot initialize the members of a base class like that.

Comment: I have edited the question, one error is included. Do I have to put all the errors?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious What is wrong with the initialization? It was compiling with no errors but that was when the function key was in both derived classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the access level of the members of class `rsa`. Even if you declare those members `public` you will still get the error. The problem is that a derived class's initialization list is run solely in the context of itself, you do not have access to base class members.

You can however access base class members (that are `public` or `protected`) in the body of a derived class constructor. Ex:

```
class public_key : public rsa
{
public:
    public_key()
    {
        n = 0;
        e = 0;
        c = 0;
        k = 0;
        end = 0;
        f = 0;
    }
};

class private_key : public rsa
{
public:
    private_key()
    {
        n = 0;
        e = 0;
        c = 0;
        k = 0;
        end = 0;
        f = 0;
    }
};
```

Though the above code uses *assignment* instead of *initialization*, it does the exact same thing under the hood for primitive types, which all of those members are.

Still, though the above code works, it is the wrong way of doing what you want. You have already written a constructor for class `rsa`, so one way to avoid duplicating code is to call your existing constructor from the initialization list.

```
class public_key : public rsa
{
public:
    public_key() : rsa()
    { }
};

class private_key : public rsa
{
public:
    private_key() : rsa()
    { }
};
```

However note that `rsa()` is the default constructor (since it has no parameters) so it will automatically be called by any constructor of the derived class (unless you specify some other `rsa` constructor in the initialization list).

```
class public_key : public rsa
{
public:
    public_key()
    { } // rsa() will be called automatically
};

class private_key : public rsa
{
public:
    private_key()
    { } // rsa() will be called automatically
};
```

But now that your derived class's have empty default constructors, you do not even need them (unless you plan to add more logic).

```
class public_key : public rsa
{
public:
    // rsa() will still be called automatically when declaring an instance of public_key
};

class private_key : public rsa
{
public:
    // rsa() will still be called automatically when declaring an instance of private_key 
};
```

As to your side note on the `key()` function, if the implementation of `key()` was the same in both child classes then yes, you only need it once in the parent class. You should always avoid code duplication so even if a small part of `key()` needed to be customized for each child class, you are better off writing a virtual function in the base class that `key()` can call as part of the calculation. Then, in each child class, override the virtual function with whatever specialization is necessary. Thus all the shared code can remain in the parent class `key()` function.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that I can call the constructor in the initialization list.

Answer (score 5):

According to the C++ Standard (12.6.2 Initializing bases and members, paragraph #2)

> Unless the mem-initializer-id names the constructor’s class, a
>   non-static data member of the constructor’s class, or a direct or
>   virtual base of that class, the mem-initializer is ill-formed.

So mem-initializers of the derived classes in your program are ill-formed and the compiler issues an error.

It is the base class constructor that should initialize its data members.

There is no any sense to define the constructor of class for example public_key  the following way as

```
public_key () : n(0), e(0), c(0), k(0), end(0), f(0) {} ;
```

because at first the constructor of the base class will be called

```
rsa () : n(0), e(0), c(0), k(0), end(0), f(0) {};
```

and it will initialize the data members.

So it is enough to write

```
rsa () {}
```

or

```
rsa () = default;
```

Comment: For reference, can you provide a link to the section you got this from? Thanks.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow So, whenever an object of a derived class is created, the constructor of the base class is called, but it doesn't initialize that object variables unless  it is explicitly specified in the constructor of the derived class! So, why the constructor of the base class is called if it doesn't initialize the derived class variables unless it explicitly stated?

Comment: @Mohamed Ahmed You are wrong. Your constructor of the base class explicitly initializes data members that specified in the mem-initializer. There is no any need to specify it in the mem-initializer of the constructor of the derived class because it will be called in any case.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow So I could just have left that constructor of the derived class empty?

Comment: @Mohamed Ahmed Yes, you may. I showed this in my post.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed Yes, you can simply leave the derived class constructors empty. In fact, if they are empty, they are not needed at all. I've updated my answer to include all of this.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Spasiba, thanks from a young Russophile.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `private_key() : rsa() {};`

Comment: You're technically correct, however you should elaborate a bit on your answer a bit :-)

Comment: I wanted to but after page refresh i saw others responses so there is no need to duplicate. I'd delete my answer if I could.

Comment: You actually can delete your own answer by clicking the link at the bottom of the post, just before the comments start. In this case you don't need to since your answer is technically correct, it's just lacking an explanation. As long as your answer is not wrong or misleading, there is no need to delete it.